# Use of undeclared identifiers even though class is created in c++

Tags: c++, class, header, non-ascii-characters, undeclared-identifier

I have created a class ShowTicket coded as follows in a header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
    class ShowTicket {
    public:
        //function that returns true if sold status is true and false if it doesnt.
        bool is_sold(void){
            if (sold_status == true){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        //function that sets sold_status to true
        void sell_seat(void){
            sold_status = true;
        }
        //prints row, seat number and sold status in casual terms
        string print_ticket(void){
            ostringstream sout;
            if(sold_status == true){
                sout<<row<<" "<<seat_number<<"sold";
            }
            else{
                sout<<row<<" "<<seat_number<<"available";
            }
            return sout.str();
        }
        //initilizes variables in constructor
        bool sold_status;
        const char* row;
        const char* seat_number;

    //constructor
        ShowTicket(const char* row, const char* seat_number, bool sold_status){
            sold_status = false;
        }
    };
```

I am using a main file with the following code to test this class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "showticket.h"
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ShowTicket myticket1(“AA”,”101");
    ShowTicket myticket2(“AA”,”102”);
  if(!myticket1.is_sold())
    myticket1.sell_seat ();
  cout << myticket1.print_ticket() << endl;
  cout << myticket2.print_ticket() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am receiving multiple "Use of undeclared identifier" errors and "Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals" errors and I do not know how to fix them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `”` in the lines 
`ShowTicket myticket1(“AA”,”101");
 ShowTicket myticket2(“AA”,”102”);`
caused the error I think.

Comment: This lab goes along with a course on edx and the main function was provided for testing the class we created. For this reason the quotations are intentional and should remain.

Comment: Just try to replace `“` and `”` by  `"`. I think an error might occur while coping/pasting the source in different OS/font/style.

Comment: Yes, that resolved most of the errors. It created a new error that confuses me "No matching constructor for initialization of 'ShowTicket'" for myticket1 and 2 even though I beleive there is

Comment: @Flann3l That means the question you are asking about is solved, and you now have a new and different problem. And when you solve that one, you are likely to find another, etc. This happens a lot in C++, one error masks several follow-up errors. You should not keep extending the scope of this question for each new uncovered problem. Try to keep working on your project, and if you get absolutely stuck again consider asking a new question instead.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but the body of `is_sold` should just be `return sold_status;`. And in `print_ticket’, `if(sold_status == true)` should just be `if(sold_status)`. The code as written works correctly but it’s unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: `ShowTicket` constructors requires 3 arguments for its 3 parameters.  The code provide only has 2 arguments.  2 ≠ 3